# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'renderRows' of undefined

Tags: angular

I am seeing below error. Can you please suggest a solution to fix it.
I am using angular 12.
The below snippet of code is from angular website, i just modified a bit to use renderRows from cdkTable to understand how it works, and its giving error for me.

```
main.966473983b5e9a722d01.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'renderRows' of undefined
    at e.ngOnInit (main.966473983b5e9a722d01.js:1)
    at KD (main.966473983b5e9a722d01.js:1)
    at dv (main.966473983b5e9a722d01.js:1)
    at fu (main.966473983b5e9a722d01.js:1)
    at Ci (main.966473983b5e9a722d01.js:1)
    at HS (main.966473983b5e9a722d01.js:1)
    at main.966473983b5e9a722d01.js:1
    at Ci (main.966473983b5e9a722d01.js:1)
    at DS (main.966473983b5e9a722d01.js:1)
    at main.966473983b5e9a722d01.js:1
```

stackblitz project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cjic6h

cdk-table-basic-example.component.ts file from where the above error is coming, please refer other files from above stackblitz project.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import {DataSource} from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable, of, pipe} from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { CdkTable } from '@angular/cdk/table';


export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cdk-table-basic-example',
  templateUrl: './cdk-table-basic-example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cdk-table-basic-example.component.css']
})
export class CdkTableBasicExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('cdkTable') cdkTable!: CdkTable<string>;
  @ViewChild('cdkTable', {read: ElementRef}) cdkTableElement!: ElementRef;
  
  constructor() { 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    const org_renderRows = this.cdkTable.renderRows;
    this.cdkTable.renderRows = () => {
      console.debug('#renderRows');
      org_renderRows.apply(this.cdkTable);
      const rows = this.cdkTable._getRenderedRows(this.cdkTable._rowOutlet);
      console.debug('#renderRows - rows count: ' + rows.length);
      if (rows.length > 0) {
         console.debug('Scroll to the End is ON - auto-scroll down to latest metric');
        rows[rows.length - 1].scrollIntoView(false);
      } else {
        console.debug('Scroll to the End is OFF - don\'t auto-scroll'); 
      }
    };

  }

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new ExampleDataSource();
}

/**
 * Data source to provide what data should be rendered in the table. Note that the data source
 * can retrieve its data in any way. In this case, the data source is provided a reference
 * to a common data base, ExampleDatabase. It is not the data source's responsibility to manage
 * the underlying data. Instead, it only needs to take the data and send the table exactly what
 * should be rendered.
 */
export class ExampleDataSource extends DataSource<PeriodicElement> {
  /** Stream of data that is provided to the table. */
  data = new BehaviorSubject<PeriodicElement[]>(ELEMENT_DATA);

  /** Connect function called by the table to retrieve one stream containing the data to render. */
  connect(): Observable<PeriodicElement[]> {
    return this.data;
  }

  disconnect() {}
}
/**  Copyright 2021 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at https://angular.io/license */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you're trying to access `cdkTable` withing `ngOnInit` hook. But when the hook is triggered your template elements don't exist yet. So `@ViewChild('cdkTable')` will be undefined at the moment.

You should move your code into another hook called `ngAfterViewInit`. It's triggered right after the view gets initialized. So you can access your template references.

More about responding to view changes you can read [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#responding-to-view-changes).

Comment: Thanks for your comment... I put the ngOnInit() method code snippet to ngAfterViewInit method, but still see same error.                                                                         ``` main.6792957c33d98ecb7d9f.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'renderRows' of undefined
    at e.ngAfterViewChecked (main.6792957c33d98ecb7d9f.js:1)
    at $D (main.6792957c33d98ecb7d9f.js:1)
    at dv (main.6792957c33d98ecb7d9f.js:1)
    at fu (main.6792957c33d98ecb7d9f.js:1)
    at Ci (main.6792957c33d98ecb7d9f.js:1)
     ```

Comment: I made a mistake in choosing the class tag in viewChild, and i have to use the suggestion you made i.e to use the code snippet in ngAfterViewInit. It worked, that error was not seen. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: happy to help you!